# How to create a VPN client for a C# app compatible with windows AND linux

Tags: c#, linux, vpn, pptp

I am trying to code a PPTP VPN client to connect to predefined SMB shares (hard-coded credentials, domain and share names - only PPTP MsChapV2 and EAP supported on server-side, which is out of my control)

I have been trying to google but I guess I am not using proper keywords.

I would ideally like to avoid DotRas, because there is no mention of linux support and also seems not maintained anymore.

Also linux support is key, since what I am trying to achieve is to be run on multiple linux servers. Ideally I would like to not be reliant on distro-specific packages, because it could possibly be used on multiple distros (Debian, RHEL)

How should I go in achieving this?

Comment: This got pretty much burried... Well whatever, will post my own answer if I figure this out myself

Comment: Hi Arimodu. I think the question did not receive enough attention because it could be improved. You could add some code that you already tried, links and explanations of similar solutions... If you make it easier for contributors, you will probably receive help!

Comment: Hi @Injuanj, Thank you for the comment, I dont yet have any code, as I honestly dont know where to start. As far as other articles go, any useful I found use the DotRas library, which as I said I would like to avoid. Anyway, should I just edit this post or make a new one (with improvements)? Thanks